# Failed to load resources status: 404 javascript with django

Tags: javascript, django

i am running javascript frontend with django backend.
Here is the structure

```
-app
--templates
---index.html
--static
---index.js
---haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
---style.css
--views.py
--urls.py
```

I can see css style in my index.html page. But the index.js file is unable to pick haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml.

The code is as follow

```
const HAARCASCADE_URI = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"

this.classifier = new cv.CascadeClassifier();
let faceCascadeFile = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
if (!this.classifier.load(faceCascadeFile)) {
 await this.createFileFromUrl(faceCascadeFile, this.classifierPath);
this.classifier.load(faceCascadeFile)
      }
```

but it say
`Failed to load haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml status: 404`

Comment: fixed by "./../static/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"